# Create an element and the ability to remove it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I use the `insertAdjacentHTML` command in click event of a button to add a `div` tag to a part of the page. Now how can I order this `div` to be remove when the rest of the page is clicked on the `body` (except for this `div`)?

Any way I create it, the `div` is created and removed quickly!

```
let newElement = '<div id="new-element">...</div>';
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newElement);
}

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
if (!document.getElementById('new-elemnt'element').contains(event.target) && document.getElementById('new-elemnt'element').length !== 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('new-elemnt'element').remove();
    }
});
```

html file:

```
<body>
    ...
    <button type="button" id="button">Create!</button>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: You should cut & paste your actual code, then you won't have that problem...

Comment: The code has been modified and the problem persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `contains` you should first check that the node exists. `getElementById` does not return a node list (so there is no `.length`). It returns either the node or `null`.

Secondly, when you have another button that must create the element, you must take care that this click is not considered as an event "outside" the new element that must remove it again. So cancel the propagation of the button click, so that it doesn't reach the other listener.

So do:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let node = document.getElementById('new-element');
    if (node) return; // It's already created
    let newElement = '<div id="new-element">new node</div>';
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newElement);
});

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let node = document.getElementById('new-element');
    if (node && !node.contains(event.target)) {
        node.remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="outside">outside</div>
<button>Add the DIV</button><br>
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Can I use `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML ('beforeend', newElement)` if I want create by clicking a button, does it work correctly?

Comment: If there is no problem, I will modify the code and you modify the answer accordingly

Comment: I corrected my question, thank you for your help